# How to know the data is retrieved from a different fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my Activity, I have "Fragment A" which has a button that Adds "Fragment B".
"Fragment A" retrieve data from a URL and shows the top 3 items, with a see all button that opens up "Fragment B" with all the items showing. is there a way to check if in Fragment B if the data was retrieved or not in Fragment A so I won't make a useless URL fetch?

```
RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

Network network = new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack());

mRequestQueue = new RequestQueue(cache, network);
mRequestQueue.start();

StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, "http...",
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
      insertintoDB();
    }
},
    new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            // Handle error
    }
});

mRequestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

Comment: Please Give your http request vode then i will tell you How to do this

Comment: save the data in shared preference so you can retrive it in fragment B to check whether frag A has data fetched or not

Comment: @Uit14bs okay hold on

Comment: @sud I already save the data in my database and retrieve it but the problem is, the data in the URL is always updated so  I can't check if the table is empty or not

Comment: ok you mean you want check is there any new data in url at the time of fragment b

Comment: @sud no I want to check in the start of fragment B if the URL was fetched in fragment A, if it was fetched then do nothing, if it was not fetched then I will fetch it and insert the data and update the list

Comment: Make a boolean variable ISFETCHED in fragment A where you call this method ISFETCHED  =true and pass int fragment B

Comment: declare your 'variable'  'globalvariable'  may be help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an instance variable of String type in Fragment A. The response that you get can be stored in a string and be sent in a bundle to Fragment B. Check for the same in Fragment B. If the string is empty or null it means that the service call was not made. Else you can use the same response

Comment: Cheers mate, with a simple modification to what you say I can achieve what I want, I can even check if the date was somehow updated first instead of just replacing it as well in the database

Answer (score 1):

Take A bool variable in Fragment A.

If Data was received in Fragment A.

Make It true .

Else False

And Send it to Fragment B If its true No need  to call again.

**Edit**

You can also Save this Boolean Variable in shared Prefrences .
And get it anywhere you want.